# How to compare argv[][] to a space character?

Tags: c, arrays, compare, space, argv

I would like to compare argv[][] to a space character. However, it won't let me. When I tried with other characters such as 'a', 'b', 'c', etc. it works, but with a space, it's doesn't work.

```
if(argv[1][1] == ' ')
{
    printf("Space Detected\n");
}
```

I tried to use the space ASCII number, no chance.
I tried to use other characters' ASCII number, it works.

I also tried '\ ', no chance.

Is there an alternative way to compare argv[][] to a space?

Restrictions: I'm not allow use use quotation marks, backslashes, on the command line.

This is code I'm working on:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{       
    printf("Program Running...\n\n");

    if((argc == 2) || ((argv[1][0] == '-') && (argv[1][1] == 'A')) )
    {
        printf("Option A.\n");
        printf("argv[1][2]: %c\n", argv[1][2]);

        printf("argv[1]: %s\n", argv[1]);

        if(argv[1][2] == ' ')
        {
            printf("Space Detected\n");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That there is no problem with this code, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: How do you expect there to be a space in any of the values? Can you give a sample of how your program is called and what you expect to happen?

Comment: Try to print `argv[1]` before the `if`, it's one of the basics of debugging, print everything that can participate to the problem. Edit: what this `printf("argv[1]: %s\n", argv[1]);` line outputs?

Comment: I just add a sample of my program and I added the print like Biduleohm wants.

Comment: How is it called from the command line. As the answer below states, `./a.out a b c` will lead to `argc = 4` and `argv = { "a", "b", "c" }`

Comment: @Biduleohm the input is ./prog -A , the output is -A but no Space Detected message.

Comment: And it's normal, `./prog -A` don't produce any spaces in `argv`. Use  `./prog "-A "` if you want a space after `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters for the program are delimited by spaces. So if you want to actually enter one you will have to use `""`, ( at least in windows )

Console example;

This is only one parameter:

```
my.exe "a b c"
```

Three parameters:

```
my.exe a b c
```

Comment: It also works, but I'm not allowed to use the quotation marks, backslashes, etc. in the command line.

Comment: @LordRixuel: What about a wrapper program that calls `exec`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm not allowed to use exec